# How to allow or disallow bitwise operations

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I'm looking for a certain type that allows perfomring flag / bitwise operations with other type but not with itself.

Imagine the following scenario:

```
public enum Suit : byte
{
    Spades      = 0x00, // bits: xx00 xxxx
    Hearts      = 0x10, // bits: xx01 xxxx
    Diamonds    = 0x20, // bits: xx10 xxxx
    Clubs       = 0x30  // bits: xx11 xxxx
}

public enum Rank : byte
{
    Ace         = 0x01, // bits: xxxx 0001
    _2          = 0x02, // bits: xxxx 0010
    //  ...
    _10         = 0x0A, // bits: xxxx 1010
    Jack        = 0x0B, // bits: xxxx 1011
    Queen       = 0x0C, // bits: xxxx 1100
    King        = 0x0D  // bits: xxxx 1101
}
```

I'd like to allow the following operation:

```
playingCardQueenOfHearts = Suit.Hearts| Rank.Queen;
```

But not the followings:

```
thisIsNonsenseInMyScenario = Suit.Spades | Suit.Hearts;
thisIsOdd = Rank.Jack | Rank.Ace;
```

Probably the `enum` isn't the best choice (in fact: it allows just the opposie I'm looking for). Is there any other type, or some way to archieve what I'm looking for?

---

I know I could cast to perform it (`queenOfHearts = (byte)Suit.Hearts| (byte)Rank.Queen`), but

a. Casting allows anything:

```
thisIsWhat = (int)Suit.Spades | (int)DayOfWeek.Sunday;
```

b. I'd like to restrict, or at least make difficult OR-ing elements of the same type:

```
thisIsNonsenseInMyScenario = Suit.Spades | Suit.Hearts;
thisIsOdd = Rank.Jack | Rank.Ace;
```

Comment: You can't do this using enums. What you can do, is define your own types and specify your own operators and what types they are allowed to do an OR with, for example.

Comment: I now `enum` won't work. As I wrote: "(in fact: it allows just the opposie I'm looking for)". I used it just as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd make a type (it could be a `class` or a `struct`) for this, e.g.

```
public struct Card
{
    public Suit Suit { get; private set; }
    public Rank Rank { get; private set; }
    public Card(Suit suit, Rank rank)
        : this()
    {
        this.Suit = suit;
        this.Rank = rank;
    }
    // include implementations for GetHashCode, Equals, ==, and !=
}
```

Use like

```
Card queenOfHearts = new Card(Suit.Hearts, Rank.Queen);
```

Comment: Getting the OR'ed `byte` value would be a plus. Any solution other than `public byte GetByteValue() { return (byte)this.Suit | (byte)this.Rank; }` ?

Comment: You'd probably also want to then make a constructor that takes a `byte` value like that and splits it into the `Suit` and `Rank`, e.g. with `byteVal & 0xF0` for the suit and `byteVal & 0x0F` for the rank (I left out casts, but that's the idea).

Comment: Exactly. That's the way I'm doing the whole project. But I didn't think at a first thought this "tiny" piece of information would also need its own class and logic :-)

Comment: You could also override the cast operator for casting Card from and to byte.

Comment: @juharr looks very nice to me: `public static implicit operator byte(Card card) {
                return (byte)((byte)card.Suit | (byte)card.Rank);
            }`